# intercept devise active_for_authentication error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to implement the 'disable user' functionality. From various source I have read that it is possible with following in my user.rb

```
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && disabled_at.blank?
  end

  def inactive_message
   'Your account has been disabled.'
  end
```

This works fine, after user has been disabled it signs him out and points to sign_in page and also shows correct inactive message.

However when a user tries to sign in(via ajax) the following happens:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
```

But in the server console its actually

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 132ms
```

This is my sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#failure_with_ajax")
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  trial_mode_days_left?(resource)
  render json: { redirect: root_path }, status: :ok
end

def failure_with_ajax
   render json: { error: t('devise.failure.invalid') }, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

The problem is when user is disabled, failure_with_ajax is never called, but its properly working when entered credentials are wrong. I don't know why the recall isnt triggered when active_for_authentication is false, and how to pass the inactive_message to the user on front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because warden.authenticate when calls active_for_authentiction does not throw the failure response with options. Its simply calls the super method for failure and the option given "recall" will not be thrown. I found a patch for it. You have to override the devise. The solution is [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/379d8c69a5c02dede6230719f3ebcc8bb95a655b)